# Access both Hotmail and Gmail from iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile-mail

When I open the Mail app on my iPhone, it has been going to my Hotmail (this was good). I just downloaded the app for Gmail, and now the Mail icon sends me to Gmail (okay). How can I access *both* Hotmail and Gmail from my iPhone 5?

Comment: Are you using the built-in Mail app? Which 'MAIL icon' are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, using the built-in Mail app. Discovered that it opens both Hotmail and Gmail, simultaneously. Very cool. Resolved. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Mail app on iOS is able to show both your Hotmail and GMail accounts. To see both of them you can either switch between them by pressing the back arrow and then choose the other mailbox or you can use the view "All Inboxes" instead where you will be able to see e-mails from both accounts in the same view. If you enter a view, the Mail application will remember which one you used and will open with that one when you launch it next time.